# How to retrieve data from AWS Lambda and display it on a static website that's hosted on AWS S3?

Tags: html, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I'm attempting to use AWS DynamoDB, Lambda, API Gateway, and S3 to create a simple website. DDB has a table and in the table is a single entry. S3 has a simple file for a HTML for a website. The goal is to display the entry located in DDB in the website, if I update the value in DDB, then refreshing the website should change the number to reflect the update in DDB. At the moment, I have a lambda function which successfully retrieves the entry from DDB. I am stuck in trying to tell the HTML file to call the lambda function and get the data back (using API Gateway). I have never worked with AWS before, forgive me if this isn't even the right approach for this goal.

Below is code for lambda function:

```js
'use-strict';

const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({region: 'us-location-x'});

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    let tableToRead = {
        TableName: 'dataStore',
        Limit: 10
    };

    docClient.scan(tableToRead, function(err,data){
       if(err){
           callback(err,null);
       } else {
           callback(null,data);
       }
    });
};
```

And this is the HTML that's on S3:

```html
<html>
    <head>
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1> This number that's in DDB </h1>

        <div id="entries">
        </div>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            //This is the link generated by API Gateway
            var API_URL = 'https://xxxxxxxxxx.execute-api.us-location-x.amazonaws.com/prod/retrieveDDB';
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'GET',
                    url: API_URL,

                    success: function(data){
                        $('#entries').html('');
                        data.Items.forEach(function(tableItem){
                            $('#entries').append('<p>' + tableItem.Row + '</p>');
                        })
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

When I run the lambda function using the "test" button, it successfully retrieves the data from the DDB. But when I try to run the HTML, it does say the header text but then it doesn't append the value from DDB. I'm assuming I'm just not understanding how to call/parse the lambda data (If I even have it set up properly).
Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: do you get `data` inside the success method? may be put `console.log(data)` and refresh the html page

Comment: @AshishModi there seems to be no data. But there is this _Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://xxxxxxxxxx.execute-api.us-location-x.amazonaws.com/prod/function. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing)._

Comment: try this - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-cors.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `cross-origin request blocked` error occurs because you are trying to access the api from a different domain (for e.g www.example.com). This is a security feature of the browsers called CORS( cross origin resource sharing requests). The browser will send a `pre-light` request to the api to check whether the call should be allowed.

A prelight request is sent as http `options` request to the api method.

There are two steps.

1. You need to enable `Cors` to the API gateway, resource method. So that it will enable the `Options` method for the resource. In short, you need to select the particular resource and then click `Enable Cors` from the actions.

Reference: Please read "Enable CORS support on a REST API resource" section of https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-cors.html

2. You should return the origin header from your lambda.

   ```
   const docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({ region: 'us-location-x' });

   exports.handler = async (event) => {
     let tableToRead = {
       TableName: 'dataStore',
       Limit: 10
     };

     const headers = {
       "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": '*'
       // other headers 
     }

     try {
       const data = docClient.scan(tableToRead).promise();
       return {
         statusCode: 200,
         body: JSON.stringify(data),
         headers: headers
       }
     } catch (error) {
       return {
         statusCode: 400,
         body: error.message,
         headers: headers
       }
     }
   };
   ```

Hope this helps. @Ashish Modi, thanks for sharing the link.

Comment: This works. I have some new errors but the CORS problem is solved. Thanks for the help

Comment: Glad to be of help

Comment: how do I get the contents of the JSON? I didn't notice until I tried getting it but right now the body is empty, it is just `{ }`, any ideas?

Comment: Then the data is empty. Can you check the scan

Comment: I would log the data to see the structure of it